# Control system: First Order with delay implementation in python

Tags: python, matlab, controls, delay

I am designing a PID Controller for a robot controller. After several runs, i notice there is a time delay . I could design a time delay block in Matlab but not sure how to implement them in python. As my pid code is in python, is there an implementation for time delay for control system ?

Comment: Try looking https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python, delays can be introduced by using

```
import sleep
time.sleep()
```

I have tried and tested this for low latency audio applications, and it works well. This can use both int and float values so millisecond order time delays are possible. As onlinejudge95 suggested, control.matlab has the pade function which can be used as well.